# Programmatically set html link to localhost or AWS domain

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, localhost

Consider:

```
"if you do want to change your password, simply click: 
<a href="http://localhost:8888/index.php?'.http_build_query (array_merge($_GET, array ('action'=>'checkcredentials', 'reset_term' => $term)))..."
```

Now consider:

```
"if you do want to change your password, simply click: 
<a href="http://my.domain/index.php?'.http_build_query (array_merge($_GET, array ('action'=>'checkcredentials', 'reset_term' => $term)))..."
```

What I would like to do is replace the `localhost:8888` part of the example with some magic that will determine whether the script should point to `localhost:8888` or `my.domain`.  I deploy the application on AWS, although I have a domain pointed at my AWS instance, and I develop and test on my local machine (hence `localhost`).

In summary, what do I need to replace `localhost:8888` with that will determine itself where to point the URL?

Comment: Most programmers have a variable or constant defined in an include file.  That file contains different information on the localhost than the server, but the file is in the same relative location.  Then, any URL can be built with the proper domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/index.php?'>
```

Or you can edit the host file and add `http://my.domain/` and point it to `localhost`